# fmincon in Matlab with non scalar objective function

Tags: matlab

I want to use Matlab to solve a constrained minimisation problem:

`min wrto (gamma,delta) the function f(gamma,delta):=[gamma,delta]`

such that

`A(gamma,delta)-B(gamma,delta)<=0`

Here a working example:

```
%main file
gamma0=0.4;
delta0=0.5;
x=fmincon(@(x) [x(1) x(2)], [gamma0 delta0], ...
          [],[],[],[],[],[], ...
          @(x) mycon(x(1),x(2))); 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%function for constraints
function [C,Ceq]=mycon(gamma,delta)
    A=randn(1)+gamma+delta;
    B=randn(1)+gamma+delta;
    C=A-B;
    Ceq=[];
end
```

However, I get as error

```
Error using fmincon (line 607)
User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.
```

Could you help me to understand how to modify the code so that `fmincon` accepts also the desired non-scalar output function?

Comment: If you want to minimise `f`, the first argument of `fmincon` should be `f` not `[x(1) x(2)]`

Comment: Thanks. My `f` is defined as `[x(1) x(2)]`.

Comment: Thanks, question updated in the arguments of `mycon`

Comment: You cannot minimise two scalars at the same time. Do you want to minimise `x(1)`, `x(2)` or a weighted version of it

Comment: You mean I cannot do it in Matlab?

Comment: You cannot mathematically do it. See one of the three options in my previous comment

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Suppose I now want to minimize `x(1)` only. However the constraint depends on `x(2)` too. Does this mean that `x(2)` will be fixed at the starting value provided?

Comment: `x(2)` may change in order to minimise `x(1)` further.

Comment: Note that in your example `x(2)` is not part of your constraint function, because you can simplify `C` to `C = randn(1) - randn(1)`.

Comment: As other have indicated, you can't do exactly what you've asked.  However you should look at [fgoalattain](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fgoalattain.html) and see if the solution it gives is close to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the minimum of a non scalar objective function is mathematically not defined. As an alternative, you can minimise one of the following options:

- `x(1)` or `x(2)` alone
- a weighted combination of both (typically [L1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), [L2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or [L_infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) norm)

**Other considerations**

- Variables that are not part of the objective function may change in order to minimise the other variables further if they are part of the constraint function.
- Using a *random generator* such as `randn` inside the objective/constraint function is (often) a bad idea, because `fmincon` calls them multiple times for different input arguments resulting in a randomly changing objective/constraint function. You should generate the random variables before the call to `fmincon` as pass these variables as arguments to your functions.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that if I minimize only `x(1)`, then `x(2)` does not move from the starting value in `fmincon`. Maybe is it just the example I am considering? And, yes, the `randn` function is just for the aim of an example.

Comment: But you should definitely move it outside your constraint function, otherwise `fmincon` may not work as expected.